# Can you use a variable for a variable call? Javascript

Tags: javascript, object

```
var name"X" = {
   data: blah blah blah
}
```

where x is a random generated number

Comment: No, but you can have an Object with a bunch of properties. `const name = {}; name[Math.floor(Math.random()*Date.now())] = {data:'blah blah blah'}` Keep in mind that numeric Object properties which are not instanceof Array will be converted to Strings, though.

Comment: Why do you think you need this? You typically can do what stackslave suggested

Comment: But yes, eval does what you are asking for if you have complete control of the input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use **eval()**:

```
var k = 'value'; 
var i = 0; 
for(i = 1; i < 5; i++) { 
    eval('var ' + k + i + '= ' + '{ abc: ' + i + ' }'  + ';'); 
} 
alert(value1.abc); 
alert(value2.abc); 
alert(value3.abc); 
alert(value4.abc);
```

or **Window object**:

```
var i; 
for(i = 1; i < 5; i++) { 
    window['value'+ i ] = { abc: i}; 
} 

alert(value1.abc); 
alert(value2.abc); 
alert(value3.abc); 
alert(value4.abc);
```

Comment: The window suggestion will always create global variables, but what the OP posted could create local variables if within functions. It also doesn't work on nodeJS.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this for the variable itself, but you could have an object with random fields.

```
var myValues = {
  ["name" + Math.random()]: "blah"
}
```